# Setting up software RAID 1 on Linux

Tags: linux, raid

So I'm trying for the first time to create a software RAID 1 array and install Linux (Mint) on it.  I've physically installed 2 500 GB SATA Seagate drives, and now I want to create a RAID 1 array.

After researching this online, my understanding is that the steps involved are the following:

1. Setup the RAID in the BIOS
2. Boot up the computer using a live CD
3. Run fdisk to create a partition on each drive
4. Run mdadm --create to make the actual array
5. Reboot and install the OS using the live CD

So, I've done step (1) and (2), booting up the computer with a Linux Mint Live CD.  When I get to step (3) I'm a bit unsure of how to proceed because of 2 reasons:

Firstly, when I run `fdisk -l` it seems I already have the necessary partitions:

```
mint / # fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00002d64

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758   976562175   488030209    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          501760   976562175   488030208   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00002d64
```

This appears to show me that `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` are *already* partitioned.  So, I'm not sure why I didn't need to create the partition myself here...

Secondly, I'm confused about the relationship between /dev/sda and /dev/sdb and this strange /dev/mapper device I see, which also reports the existence of my 2 hard drives.

But where I *really* run into trouble is when I actually try using `mdadm`.  Assuming that the partitions are okay, I try to create the RAID 1 array as follows:

```
mdadm --create  --verbose /dev/md0 --level=mirror --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda /dev/sdb
```

This gives me the error:

```
mdadm: super1.x cannot open /dev/sda: Device or resource busy
mdadm: failed container membership check
mdadm: cannot open /dev/sda: Device or resource busy
```

So, I've googled around trying to figure out what this means, but the best I get is that the drives may somehow be in use by the OS - but I can't see how.  My only guess is that perhaps the fact that the drives appear as icons in the Mint GUI means they are considered in use:

[image]

So, why does `mdadm` report that my drives are busy?

Comment: Do you want so set up a normal Linux software RAID (using mdadm) **or** a intel IRST fake RAID array (which requires setting things in the BIOS, which is something not done when you use mdadm) ?

Comment: Or did you want to use LVM? Which is a third method. For all practical purposes select one of them rather than trying to create a mix of all three.

Comment: Confused on step 1, setup what RAID in BIOS for MDRAID?  Are you trying to setup RAID using two drives because fdisk shows no partitions on second drive (sdb).  Also, I think you have to set the partition type to a RAID autodetect using fdisk (currently 83 instead of fd).  Have you tried umount on sda and sdb to make sure they are not in use?